# How do I calculate the pressure on the walls of my MD simulation?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, computational-physics, simulations, ideal-gas

So I've built a simulation in vpython where I have multiple hard balls that collide with each other and with the walls of the cube I've placed them in. I then replaced the values for their radius and masses to be equal to a hydrogen atom in the hope that I could calculate the pressure on the walls of my cube from the simulation and then compare it with the predicted pressure by the Ideal Gas Law. The problem is that I don't know how to measure the pressure in my simulation. My attempt at that was to use that force is the change of momentum divided by time so I took the sum of the change of momentum that occurred due to ball-wall collisions and divided that by the area and the total time. I did that because the correct way would be to sum all the changes of momentum divided by the time the collision took, the problem is that I don't know the time a hydrogen atom would take to recoil from a collision to a wall, so I'm just averaging everything.
The pressure measured becomes constant after 10 seconds(in which boltzman distribution takes place) but the problem is that the pressure is often off by a factor of 10^-2 from the predicted by PV=nRT...
How can I solve this?

Comment: From a chemists perspective (no hands-on experience yet on MD), I speculate you might be in a better position to exchange the approach of an ideal gas (i.e., $pV = nRT$), which assumes that the gas molecules' volume is insignificant vs. the volume of their container by the van-der-Waals equation where the molecules have a significant volume.  This is because your model assumes "hard (= incompressible) balls". Depending on the accessible volume, one of the corrections ($(V_m - b)$ leads into the idealization of $pV = nRT$. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation.

Comment: #2 If you want to start on a conservative approach, many experimentally determined van-der-Waals parameters are tabulated, including for gases known to be mono-atomic (like helium, neon, krypton), instead of more complicated molecular ones; e.g., on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page).